Character gets access to universal control panel, fights ancient human already there
This XKCD reminds me of a story in Asimov's magazine from the 1980s or 1990s about a meta-universe in which actions affect the "settings" of our universe - how the laws of physics, etc. work.  I think the main character winds up in this meta-universe, and finds that a primitive human has been there for millennia, and fights him for control. If I recall correctly the meta-verse looks like a forest, but doing things like breaking branches has strange effects in our world. As I recall, the control panel was very metaphorical - it was very hard to connect what you did in the "control-panel" world to what happened in our world.
This is not the same story discussed in this question (The Fundamental Things by Shepard), but they are in the same ballpark.

Direct link to the comic rather than the explain site: xkcd 1620
